# Changing content depending on refferal

Tags: http, apache-http-server

On my personal website, I occasionally write some development related tutorials. It has brought to my attention that another website literary copies my tutorials, it even leaves the links to source and pictures directly on his site.

What I would like to do is redirect all request for images to another image notifying the reader that the website has no access to the requested image. However, I want all website on my server not to be affected. So all requests from 127.0.0.1, and 195.189.182.105 should be allowed.

I am currently running an Debian server with ISPConfig (running Apache 2.x, PHP 5.2.3 ect).

Can I do this in Apache?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking out for is binding image hot-linking.

See this [wiki](http://wiki.apache.org/httpd/DisableImageHotLinking) page for details.

Comment: Great! Thanks alot. That worked. Checked it for http://paulpeelen.com/2011/03/17/xcode-4-ios-4-3-hello-world/ and the "theif"'s website doesn't show any images anymore.